# rendering a vtkRenderWindow in a pre-existin QGLWindow in Linux does not work

Tags: python, qt, opengl, vtk

I want to show a `VTK` render window within a `Qt` application (developed in Python). In this case, the interaction is handled by `Qt` and I created the class [QVTKWidget](https://github.com/vais-ral/CILViewer/blob/master/Wrappers/Python/ccpi/viewer/QVTKWidget.py) to pass the interaction from `Qt` to `VTK`.

In Windows it all works well, but when I use the same code in Linux `VTK` renders in its own window.

I tracked down the issue to the following: to instruct `VTK` (`vtkRenderWindow`) to [use](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.html#a67ac20abb7f38a6f703d162f214c8824) a pre-existing window I use the following lines [here](https://github.com/vais-ral/CILViewer/blob/master/Wrappers/Python/ccpi/viewer/QVTKWidget.py#L294):

```py
self._RenderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
WId = self.winId()    # self is a QWidget
self._RenderWindow.SetWindowInfo(str(int(WId)))
```

If I comment out the line with `SetWindowInfo` on Windows, VTK renders in its own window (though the interaction is still handled by Qt).

The problem is that in Linux `SetWindowInfo` doesn't seem to work and it all behaves as if it wasn't passed at all.

A minimal example requires `vtk`, `pyqt >=5`, the [QVTKWidget.py](https://github.com/vais-ral/CILViewer/blob/master/Wrappers/Python/ccpi/viewer/QVTKWidget.py) module (which is the one containing the above mentioned lines) and the following file.

I installed everything with conda:

```sh
conda create --name SO vtk pyqt python numpy -c conda-forge
conda activate SO
```

```py
from PyQt5.QtOpenGL import QGLWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import vtk
import sys
from ccpi.viewer.QVTKWidget import QVTKWidget


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('DVC Configurator')
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1200, 600)

        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.vl = QVBoxLayout()

        self.vtkWidget = QVTKWidget(viewer=mv)

        self.vl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        self.frame.setLayout(self.vl)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        closeAction = QAction("Close", self)
        closeAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        closeAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(closeAction)

        self.show()

    def setApp(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def loadFile(self, fname):
        pass

    def close(self):
        self.app.quit()

def main():
    err = vtk.vtkFileOutputWindow()
    err.SetFileName("viewer.log")
    vtk.vtkOutputWindow.SetInstance(err)

    print ("Starting ... ")

    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Window()
    gui.setApp(App)

    sys.exit(App.exec())

class mv(object):
    def __init__(self, ren=None, renWin=None, iren=None, **kwargs):
        if ren == None:
            self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        else:
            self.ren = ren
        if renWin == None:
            self.renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
        else:
            self.renWin = renWin
        if iren == None:
            self.iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
        else:
            self.iren = iren
        # holder for list of actors    

        self.renWin.SetSize(200,200)
        self.renWin.AddRenderer(self.ren)

        self.iren.SetInteractorStyle(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())
        self.iren.SetRenderWindow(self.renWin)
        self.iren.Initialize()
        self.ren.SetBackground(.1, .2, .4)

        cone = vtk.vtkConeSource()
        cone.Update()
        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(cone.GetOutputPort())
        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)
        self.ren.AddActor(actor)
        #self.iren.Start()
        self.iren.Render()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This should pop up a Qt window with a VTK render window inside with a 3D cone that you can interact with. It is expected to open 1 window, which is the case in Windows, not in Linux.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I voted your reopen your question with the added code, thanks. Although I can't test it myself because I'm missing `PyQt5.QtOpenGL` and I'm not sure I can find a version of python on my system where both that and vtk works.

Comment: it turns out that my QVTKWidget class uses a vtkRenderWindowInteractor rather than a vtkGenericRenderWindowInteractor. See https://discourse.vtk.org/t/qvtkwidget-render-window-is-outside-main-qt-app-window/1539/8

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! If the question above contains enough information for it to make sense, we can get your question reopened and you can post your solution as an answer. If the core of the problem was something different from what you asked (I can't tell because I'm not familiar with Qt), then this might make less sense. What do you think?

Comment: Well, the core of the problem was correctly identified and was in the VTK class I was using. If that is too specific to me or more general I cannot say. I had seen this behaviour before and at least this time I understood the solution. It'd be great to post the solution.

Comment: Your question is open now; you're welcome to post a self-answer.